# Nuance of benchmark, criterion and so on

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I was wondering if someone could tell me about the slight semantic nuance between the words bellow and when each one can be used:

> - Benchmark
> - Criterion
> - Yardstick
> - Touchstone

For me 'benchmark' and 'criterion' mean the same and 'yardstick'and 'touchstone' mean the same too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of overlap between these terms, and no very clear distinctions; but if you use them this way you won't go far wrong:

- *Criterion* is the most general of these terms. It means a *parameter*: a category of evaluation. It may be either a scalar value, which varies across a range, or a binary value, which is either present or not. For instance, college admission boards may employ both scalar criteria such as a numeric assessment of a candidate's ability to perform complex reasoning and binary criteria such as the candidate's participation in athletics or community service.
- A *yardstick*, as the name implies, is a measuring tool: the device or method by which the value of a scalar criterion is measured. The Scholastic Assessment Test (SAT) and grade point average, for instance, are yardsticks for measuring academic ability.
- A *benchmark* is a single point whose value is known and which can therefore be used as a standard of comparison. It could be a minimum value which must be equalled or surpassed, or a maximum value towards which everybody aspires, or something in between, such as an average or median value. A benchmark is not a criterion, but a reference point for evaluating conformity to a criterion. For instance, a college admission board might set a 1000 score on the 1600-point Scholastic Assessment Test as a minimal benchmark for admission.
- A *touchstone* is technically a device for sampling the color and composition of precious metals, but in non-technical uses it means a kind of loose, 'seat-of-the-pants' yardstick for intangible or unmeasurable values. A famous example is A.E.Housman's touchstone for a 'true poem': does it make the hairs at one's chin bristle if one repeats it silently while shaving? A college admission board might employ 'memorability' as a touchstone: which candidates' essays do I remember after I have read a hundred of them?

Comment: Just one more question; do you confirm my understanding? As I understood, a 'benchmark' or a 'criterion' is a standard by which you can judge other things --- and a 'yardstick' is something that you compare another things with it in order to discover how good it is.

Comment: Nevertheless after reading your answer for three times I see not a big difference between these words. Can I ask you to clarify their differences a little bit more (of course if its possible?) :) I know it is very difficult to convey such slight nuances to a non native like me. but believe me; in my language for all of these words there is only one single equivalent and it is critical to know clearly how they differ to be able to use the properly.

Comment: @A-friend Suppose you are picking basketball players. You have three *criteria*: height, skill, and will. You can measure height with a tape measure: the tape measure is a *yardstick*. Or you can say "They have to be taller than 185cm"; 185cm is a *benchmark*. You can measure skill by stats: "How many points did they score in college competition? That's a *yardstick*. Or you can say "They have to have been starters for a Division I college program." That's a benchmark. But what about "will"? How do you measure that? ...

Comment: ... Perhaps you employ a *touchstone* "He was his conference's leading scorer, but he only scored 10 points in the championship game--but he had 18 assists, and his team won the game. This is a guy who wants to win, and sacrifices his personal stats to do so. Pick him!"

Comment: Now everything is clear. Just one other related question. Can we compare a 'benchmark' with an 'index' and a 'criteria' with a 'factor' or a 'metric'? :)

Comment: @A-friend A 'benchmark' is not an 'index' in any sense of 'index' I am familiar with, but it might be in your discipline. A 'criterion' (that is the singular form) is, loosely, a factor, but not necessarily a 'metric', which is something measured or something with which something is measured.

Comment: Dear StoneyB, I have thought a lot, but couldn't equalize a word with the term 'touchstone' in my mother language; though according to many dictionaries, touchstone has no difference with criterion. But I am sure all dictionaries have an insufficient description on it. I would appreciate it if you could provide another example for me through which I could more easily recognize the difference of these two words. I mean "Touchstone" and "Criterion".

Comment: @A-friend In distinguishing these words we're really talking less about 'meaning' than about 'use'. **Criterion** is both a very general and a very formal term. Laws and regulations and professional associations talk about *criteria* when they are making a formal list of all the matters to be taken into account in reaching a judgment or decision, and they define these matters very carefully. *Criteria* are ordinarily plural (which is why so few people know the singular form!): usually many criteria go into any judgment...

Comment: ... A *touchstone*, by contrast, is almost always singular: it is *the* single most important question you bring to making a judgment. For instance, in elections many people reduce their decision to a single *touchstone* issue: what is  the candidate's position on abortion or immigration or Obamacare. And it is usually not narrowly defined but very vague and impressionistic, probably because it has the word *touch* in it (few people know why a *touchstone* is called that): we don't use *touchstone* for things that can be measured but for qualities that are felt.