# What do we do with a benchmark?

Tags: word-usage, idiomatic-language, collocations

Considering the concept of a [benchmark](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/43813), in the sense of a single point of reference.

What does one say, when, for example, a person has achieved a score that is higher than some *benchmark score*?

I guess you could say they ...

- ... passed the benchmark
- ... surpassed the benchmark
- ... met the benchmark
- ... attained the benchmark (?)
- ... achieved the benchmark (?)

None of those sound exactly right to me.

Comment: The link is too long to fit into a comment, but try feeding the search string **have * the benchmark** into [Google NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+benchmark&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20benchmark%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthe%20benchmark%3B%2Cc0) to see which Past Participles occur most often in place of that wild-card asterisk. Or I can save you the trouble by pointing out that ***outperformed, met, reached, achieved,...*** all occur quite often. That doesn't mean any of your *other* suggestions are "incorrect", though.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Thanks, I did not know about Google NGrams.

Comment: Flagging up the NGram approach was my primary reason for commenting! But even if you *had* known about it, you still might not have realised that it can do wildcards, AND/OR you might not have realised that it would be a good idea to include a word like ***have*** or ***has*** in the "search string" so that most of the matches would be for past participles (without that, you'd be swamped by irrelevant results for ***of, as, to, in, is,...***).